# Ошбика обработки входных данных из текстового файла

Tags: c#

Есть файл с содержимым вида:

```
AAAAAAA2
*bbbb1
*cccc1
DDDDDDD7
*bbbb3
*cccc3
*gggggg1
```

Должно получиться:

```
AAAAAAA,*bbbb,1
AAAAAAA,*cccc,1
DDDDDDD,*bbbb,3
```

но выходит:

```
AAAAAAA,bbbb,1
AAAAAAA,cccc,1
DDDDDDD,cccc,1--лишняя хрень
DDDDDDD,bbbb,3
DDDDDDD,cccc,3
DDDDDDD,gggggg,1
```

В чем проблема?

```
var mas = new string[3];
        var stringi = new List<string>();
        string n;

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"1.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)

            {
                if (line != null && Char.IsLetter(line[0]))
                {
                    char[] res = line.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray();
                    mas[0] = new string(res);
                }
                else if (line != null && line.StartsWith("*"))
                {
                    char[] res1 = line.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray();
                    mas[1] = new string(res1);
                    char[] res2 = line.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray();
                    mas[2] = new string(res2);
                }

                if (line != null && mas[0] != null & mas[1] != null & mas[2] != null)
                {
                    n = mas[0] + "," + mas[1] + "," + mas[2] + "\r\n";
                    stringi.Add(n);
                    File.WriteAllLines("4.txt", stringi);
                }
            }
        }

        Close();
```

Comment: Непонятна логика кода. Почему после `AAAAAAA2` должны захватиться обе строки, начинающиеся со `*`, а после `DDDDDDD7` — только одна?

Comment: после DDDDDDD7 -должны захватываться все последующие  с * , но первым захватывается предыдущее значение AAAAAAA,cccc,1
DDDDDDD,cccc,1--лишняя хрень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (если предположить, что в примере лишняя только `DDDDDDD,cccc,1`):

```
var result = new List<string>();

string currentGroup = "";

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"1.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))
{
    if (!line.StartsWith("*"))
    {
        currentGroup = new String(line.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        var sub = new String(line.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
        var number = new String(line.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

        result.Add(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", currentGroup, sub, number));
    }
}

result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

File.WriteAllLines("4.txt", result);
```

Comment: выводит ,,1
,,1
,,3 вместо AAAAAAA,bbbb,1

Comment: @user182307 вы привели весь текстовый файл? я использовал пример из вашего вопроса - на нем работает. Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) только убрал.

Comment: @user182307 возможно у вас там русские буквы - тогда верните Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)  на место (подправил код ответа)

Comment: Большое спасибо код рабочий, действительно забыл про кодировку